# Extracting AST from Powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, abstract-syntax-tree

Given a powershell script (for example $C=$a+$b; $d = $e*$f), I am trying to access every node in the script's AST.

Currently, I’ve tried:

```
$code = {$C=$a+$b; $d = $e*$f}
$astVisitor = [System.Management.Automation.Language.AstVisitor]
$visit = $code.Ast.Visit($astVisitor)
```

but I’m running into the following error: Cannot find an overload for "Visit" and the argument count: "1".

What's the right way to access the ast data structure and use the visit method correctly to loop through every node in the tree? I didn't find the documentation of the [ast api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) very helpful.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but your `$astVisitor` contains `AstVisitor` class type information, not an `AstVisitor` instance.  Although, I see that both `AstVisitor` and the derived `AstVisitor2` are both `abstract`, so I have no idea what instance you'd actually create and how!

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/09/26/learn-how-it-pros-can-use-the-powershell-ast/ has a way to do it using `$code.Ast.FindAll({$true}, $true) | foreach-object {..}` if that helps. But it's not using the Visitor.

Answer (score 5):

> I am trying to access every node in the script's AST

If you simply want to see nested elements for yourself, use the `FindAll()` method:

```
$code.Ast.FindAll({$true},$true)
```

The first argument acts as a predicate with which you can filter the results.

If for example you only want to extract string expressions, you could do:

```
$code = {
  "A string"
  123
  Get-Process
  & {
    'Another string'
  }
}

$Code.Ast.FindAll({
  param($Ast) 

  $Ast -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantExpressionAst]
}, $true)
```

Second argument is a boolean indicating whether to traverse nested scriptblocks. Using the example from above, but changing the second argument value to `$false` would yield the same result, except for the second string.

A couple of tools for visualizing the tree in a GUI already exists, such as [ShowPSAst](https://github.com/lzybkr/ShowPSAst) and [ASTExplorer](https://github.com/zloeber/ASTExplorer).

If you want to use an AstVisitor, [here's an example of implementing the `ICustomAstVisitor`](https://github.com/IISResetMe/MeasureScript/blob/master/Classes/AstVisitor.class.ps1) interface in PowerShell 5.0.

The sample above is from the ScriptLineProfiler sample in the 3.0 SDK. Notice the modification to statements in the `VisitStatements()` method, should give you some ideas as to how you can modify/recreate the individual nodes